# Using Output Filters WITH Reverse Proxy on Apache 2.4

Tags: apache, reverse-proxy

We have an Apache 2.4 installation on Centos 7. We want to use this Apache server as a Reverse Proxy for an existing website and also apply an OutputFilter before the content is returned to the client.

If I configure the Reverse Proxy only, it works correctly.
If I configure the Output Filter only, on a locally served index.html, that also works.
When I configure the Reverse Proxy AND the Output Filter, the Output Filter is not applied to the content served.
Is there some conflict between Proxy and FIlters ? Any help appreciated.

For testing purposes the source site is http://www.alice-in-wonderland.net.
The test filter is a simply text replace of all instances of "Alice" with "Vicky".
[ f.y.i. Our production filter is a call to Google Cloud Translate API ]

The httpd.conf (snippet ) is

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName mobile.betyetu.co.mz
  DocumentRoot "/var/www/betyetu"
  ErrorLog "logs/betyetu-error_log"
  TransferLog "logs/betyetu-access_log"
  #
  # SSL defintions
  #
  # SSLEngine on
  # SSLCertificateFile "/etc/ssl/certs/server.crt"
  # SSLCertificateKeyFile "/etc/ssl/certs/server.key"
  #
  # define an external output filter for translation of English to Portuguese
  #
  ExtFilterDefine filtEN2PT mode=output intype=text/html outtype=text/html cmd="
/var/www/betyetu/notAlice.sh"
  AddOutputFilter  filtEN2PT html
  #
  # Enable Reverse Proxy
  #

  ProxyPass "/"  "http://www.alice-in-wonderland.net/"
  ProxyPassReverse  "/"  "http://www.alice-in-wonderland.net/"
</VirtualHost>
```

The output filter is

```
#!/usr/bin/bash
#
# Test for output Filter on 127.0.0.1:81
# Substitute "Vicky" for "Alice"
# 
/usr/bin/sed 's/Alice/Vicky/g'
```

Comment: Hi Tony, Are you able to fix this issue

Comment: Greetings. I'll close the ticket. We switched to a nginx solution.

Comment: That would explain why it doesn't work for me either... the filter is probably totally ignore in this case.